# Using con statement in raster calculator to include raster as condition in existing raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, raster-calculator, con

I'm doing an assignment where we have to use a Weighted overlay to generate a raster of suitable places to plant crops. I've put all the factors in the weighted overlay and generated my output but now I need to consider the constraints. These are built up areas and conservation areas that need to be classified as 'not suitable'. The lecturer says that we need to use a CON statement in the raster calculator to get the '0' values from the constraint's raster put onto the weighted overlay raster.

But, I have no idea how to do that. All the resources I have found use the format CON (in raster = 0, x, y) but I don't know how to fill the Y value with an entire raster (the Weighted raster)... if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Y value is the values "if false" (and X is the value "if true"). You can enter a constant values (e.g. could be 0 in your case), a layer (could be your weighted overlay raster). Also, testing equality in the raster calculator is done by using "==" ("=" will not work)

Comment: do I use the name of the raster layer as the if false value?